# Footer accept payment image not showing

Tags: footer

I added the following code under design tab in footer area

```
<img title=”Accepting MC, VISA, AMEX, DISCOVER” src=”https://inspirer.ca/credit_card_logos_16.jpg” alt=”Accepting MC, VISA, AMEX, Discover” width=”336″ height=”50″ />
```

But the front page shows me [image]

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a Magento specific problem.

Answer (score 2):

The code should read:

```
<img src="https://inspirer.ca/credit_card_logos_16.jpg" alt="Accepting MC, VISA, AMEX, Discover" width="336" height="50" />
```

Which will display as follows:

[image: Accepting MC, VISA, AMEX, Discover]